# Laplace Transformation of sin(t+1)*DiracDelta(t)

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, laplace-transform, dirac-delta

why is Laplace transformation of `sin(t+1)*DiracDelta(t)` = sin(1)?
I thought:

`L[f(t)-u(t-a)] = e^(-as)*L[f(t+a)]` and according to this formula it gave me `e^(2s)` and why wolfram answers back `sin(1)`?

Answer (score 3):

The Dirac delta satisfies $$\int_0^\infty g(t)\,\delta(t)\,dt=g(0).$$ Then
$$
\mathcal L[\sin(t+1)\,\delta(t)](s)=\int_0^\infty \sin(t+1)\,e^{-st}\,\delta(t)\,dt=\sin(0+1)\,e^{-0}=\sin1
$$
(which is not zero). 
In your other formula you don't have a Dirac delta, but a *unit impulse function*.

Comment: thanks for the clarification